# UItextView save contents, after app terminates

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5, uitextview

I am new to Objective C,iOS Development(I'm using Xcode 5) and maybe this is going to be a very basic question, but i've tried hard to find an answer and all i see is very advanced stuff. I'm creating an app where the user can type down to a UITextView notes and then save them,  but when the app is terminated (not just enters background) when i relaunch it everything is lost. How could i retain what the user has typed?
Every help is highly appreciated.
Thank You Very Much,
George

Comment: where u save ur data ?@george pgs

Comment: For a beginner there isn't a completely straightforward solution. You really only have a few options. 1)Core data - little complicated and overkill. 2) NSUserDefaults - not meant for storing large amounts of data, really for settings. 3) Nscoding/Archiver - this is where you serialise the data and save it to disk, reload on launch. - this is best for you IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save it in

```
[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults]
```

after that, when you start the app, retrive the info from the NSUserDefaults.